# cross validation output interpretation from survival analysis

Tags: cross-validation, survival-analysis

I have performed a cross validation using the errorest function, but am not sure how to interpret the output Brier score. Is there a way to visualise the cross validation? Any other suggestions how to perform an visualise the CV.

```
library(ipred)


    df.t <- structure(list(time = c(1796, 1644.04166666667, 
    606.041666666667, 1327.04166666667, 665, 2461, 1824, 1554.04166666667, 
    601.958333333333, 1638.95833333333), status = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Comb2 = c("Low", "Low", 
    "High", "Low", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Low")), row.names = c("1025", 
    "1101", "1198", "1330", "1393", "1428", "1473", "1676", "175", 
    "1754"), class = "data.frame")


    err <- errorest(Surv(time, status) ~Comb2, data=df.t, model=survfit,
         predict=NULL, est.para=control.errorest(k=5))
```

out:

```
Call:
errorest.data.frame(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ Comb2, data = df.t.top, 
    model = survfit, predict = NULL, est.para = control.errorest(k = 5))

     5-fold cross-validation estimator of Brier's score

Brier's score:  0.2622
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your code working so I can't reproduce the above, however some comments:

1. The brier score is a scoring rule and in a survival setting there is no known baseline value. What that means is that you actually cannot interpret this value on its own, '0.2622' could be 'good' or 'bad', but without another model to compare to it is meaningless.
2. Visualising a score across folds also does not provide useful information. You should only ever look at the mean score across all folds.
3. Visualising the CV also does not make sense. The purpose of CV is to get the average prediction across all folds, inspection between folds does not provide useful information.

Since you're asking for other suggestions I will plug my package which can easily obtain predictions, compare multiple models, and also visualise prediction error curves. Here's an example with your data:

```
library(mlr3); library(mlr3proba)

set.seed(1)

# create data
df.t <- data.frame(
  time = c(1796, 1644.04166666667, 
           606.041666666667, 1327.04166666667, 665, 2461, 1824, 1554.04166666667, 
           601.958333333333, 1638.95833333333),
  status = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L),
  Comb2 = factor(c("Low", "Low",  "High", "Low", "High",
 "Low", "Low", "High", "High", "Low"))
)
rownames(df.t) <- c("1025",  "1101", "1198", "1330", "1393", "1428", "1473", "1676", 
"175", "1754")

# convert data to 'task'
task = TaskSurv$new("dft", df.t, time = "time", event = "status")

# get Cox PH learner
cox = lrn("surv.coxph")

# use 5-fold cross-validation
cv = rsmp("cv", folds = 5)

# resample
rr = resample(task, cox, cv)

# get brier/graf score
rr$aggregate(msr("surv.brier"))

# get prediction
rr$prediction()

# inspect individual predictions
rr$predictions("test")

# compare to Kaplan-Meier baseline
km = lrn("surv.kaplan")

# make benchmark experiment
design = benchmark_grid(task, list(cox, km), cv)

# run experiment
bm = benchmark(design)

# get brier score
bm$aggregate(msr("surv.brier"))
```

Comment: Your CV does not make new feature-selections for each fold? So there will be a bias there.

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to, this is standard cross-validation. Perhaps I've misunderstood your question although in your original post it looks like your model only uses one feature?